# Can you predefine allowed fields on documents in Meteor/MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, collections

I searched everywhere for this but I can't find anything on that matter. If you don't predefine fields in MongoDB, couldn't a user with Insert permission then Insert a document with every kind of field he wants? Via Collection.insert? If I am thinking correctly here, is there a way to restrict this?

Answer (score 0):

This is my personal preference. Because fieldNames param in
`Collections.update(userId, doc, fieldNames)` only gives top-level fields in doc. So if you are having nested fields it is very hard to track.

So I don't use collection allow/deny rules. Without allow deny rules  Collections.insert/Collections.update does nothing on client. Instead I am using Meteor methods to update/delete documents to collections, so I can decide which exact fields should update/insert.

Answer (score 0):

You can restrict inserting any kind of fields in these two ways:

1. Use `collection.allow/deny`(http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/allow) - the `insert` callback has a `doc` parameter, which contains the exact document that user wants to insert - you can check the content of it and deny the insertion if you spot fields that are not allowed.
2. Use SimpleSchema (https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-simple-schema) and Collection2 (https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-collection2) packages to define the schema and attach it to your collection - it will prevent the insertion if a document has additional/missing fields (or fields of not expected type).